# Help! Please help me! The site is completely messed up!

Tags: discussion

Help me please!

The site is completely messed up! Everything is blue. Do I have a virus? They told me I would not get a virus on UBUNTU!!

[image]
Please help me or I switch back to windows! This should work!!!

Thanks you many much

Comment: The funniest part is to see Oli with 9k rep! :D

Comment: No reproducible... :/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about unicorns :(

Answer (score 14):

### April Fools!

But in all seriousness* you couldn't possibly *not* want colored comments.. ***could you?***

<sup>*Not serious at all</sup>